# PyQtGraph: Checking if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION')

Tags: python, sys, pyqtgraph, qtgui, qtcore

I'm reading some simple examples of using PyQtGraph, and I noticed that many people write:

```
if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Instead of the following line only:

```
QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

When should I use these two conditions in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to understand `QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()` what you do is execute the Qt event loop.

Let's analyze what each condition implies:

- **`sys.flags.interactive`**: This flag is activated when you execute the code in interactive mode through [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) e.g. when you use the Python console (read [Interactive Mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode) for more information). If it is different from 1 then it implies that the Qt event loop does not need to be used since the REPL already has an event loop.
- **`hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION')`**: pyqtgraph uses PyQt as a backend so if you do not have PyQt installed, the Qt eventloop will not be possible, so that condition verifies the installation of PyQt, and if your application is not installed, it will not work.

So the first condition is recommended that you use it so that your code does not have problems in the cases that you use or not the interactive mode.

Instead, use the second condition so that you are sure that you have PyQt installed as a backend but keep in mind that it currently also supports PySide and PySide2, so in those cases you should not use that condition.

Comment: Thank you for these details, but do these two lines mean "if (the Qt event loop does not need to be used) or (you do not have PyQt installed), then execute the Qt event loop"?! or I misunderstood something in your answer?

Comment: @Abdulkader I have not analyzed `(sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION')` but only `sys.flags.interactive == 1` and `hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION')` separately.

Comment: @Abdulkader So if you want if we make a summary, let's first understand that the "or" implies that it is enough for one to be true to execute. So `if X or Y: foo()` is equivalent to `if X: foo()` `if Y: foo()`.

Comment: @Abdulkader Then let's analyze the first "if": `if sys.flags.interactive != 1: QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()` means that if it is the non-interactive mode the event loop must be created.

Comment: @Abdulkader On the other hand, the second "if" `hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):` means if Qt is not installed then do not start the eventloop since it cannot be created.

Comment: @Abdulkader So the first condition will make your script **run** for interactive or non-interactive mode, but the second will make it **not run** unless PyQt is installed.